# Orthogonal matrix decomposition

Tags: matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

Consider an orthogonal matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ that can be decomposed as $\boldsymbol{A}=\boldsymbol{BCD}$, where $\boldsymbol{A}$, $\boldsymbol{B}$, $\boldsymbol{C}$, $\boldsymbol{D} \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$. Suppose $\boldsymbol{C}$ is a diagonal matrix with normalized complex exponential diagonal elements, and all the elements of $\boldsymbol{B}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$ share a common modulus. **Then must $\boldsymbol{B}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$ be scaled orthogonal matrices?**

Comment: to be clear, all elements of $B$ and $D$ sharing a common modulus means $ \vert b_{i,j}\vert=\vert b_{1,1}\vert= \vert d_{i,j}\vert$ for all $i, j \in \big\{1,2,...,N\big\}$ correct?

Comment: @user8675309 right

Comment: other things that need clarifying **(i.)** what is a 'normalized complex exponeitial diagonal matrix" and **(ii.)** You say that $A \in O_N\big(\mathbb C\big)$ and conjecture that up to re-scaling $B,D \in O_N\big(\mathbb C\big)$ but do you actually mean $\in U_N\big(\mathbb C\big)$ in all these cases?  These are quite different groups.

Comment: @user8675309 (i.) $|c_{i,i}|=1,~ i\in\left\{1,\ldots,N\right\}$ (ii.) Sorry, I mean $\boldsymbol{A}$ is an unitary matrix, and wondering whether $\boldsymbol{B}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$ should be scaled unitary matrices. So the question should be unitary matrix decomposition.